# `web_accessible_resources` images in content scripts not working in chrome 89.0.4389.82

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and it involves a small overlay on sites with an icon of the product/brand. Last week, I rendered this fine. My content script is a simple React.js app that mounts into a newly created div on any arbitrary page and creates a `<img>` element:

```html
<img className="image" src={chrome.runtime.getURL(logo)} />
```

This worked great and it required an entry in the manifest:

```json
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "/*.png",
            ],
            "matches": []
        }
    ],
```

However, I came back to the project this week and the icon no longer displays. No changes to code or manifest over the weekend. All I can think of is a chrome update introduced a bug.

The console displays this:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://gnncmcgealbfkmmiahajhhlhpgfldijh/ccffc3aeb870eaff711b.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

I wondered if `*` support was removed so I added the filename explicitly:

```
            "resources": [
                "ccffc3aeb870eaff711b.png",
                "/ccffc3aeb870eaff711b.png"
            ],
```

Both with and without a `/` because there are no docs for this manifest yet for some reason.

This didn't work either.

The only documentation for this is here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#web-accessible-resources but it claims most of the fields are unused.

This *definitely* worked last week though, I even have a screenshot (though I cannot share publicly due to NDA reasons) so you'll all just have to trust me on that one!

Does anyone know of any additional manifest configuration required to get this working again? Chrome documentation seems to be lagging behind. Is this a bug or just a lack of documentation or feedback from the extension engine or browser?

Thanks!

Comment: `"matches": []` should be `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`